# Android Location services not working after a few days

Tags: android, background, location

I've implemented an Android geolocation tracking application. Since the application runs in background I noticed that after a few days the it stops getting locations unless the device gets restarted.

I am importing `com.google.android.gms.location.*` api for getting locations.

I need to configure any thing for the application?

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please paste your code and some logs.

Comment: Do you use a [service](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) for doing the tracking? Because the application will be killed.

Comment: Are you using service? Service should not be used for a very very long running work. It may be destroyed.